# Двусвязный список с++

Tags: c++, list, struct

Пишу задачу на реализацию дека: из первого двусвязного списка переписать во второй список элементы после максимума. Вся проблема в том, что элементы второго дека не выводятся, т.е. на экране появляется уведомление о том, что я добавил в дек элемент, но при вызове функции вывода ни один из элементов не выводится. Не могу найти ошибку. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct doubleList {

    int data;
    doubleList* ptrNext;
    doubleList* ptrPrev;

};
doubleList* push(doubleList* head, int value) {

    doubleList* newHead = new doubleList;
    newHead->data = value;
    newHead->ptrPrev = NULL;
    newHead->ptrNext = head;
    if (head == NULL) {
        return newHead;
    }

    head->ptrPrev = newHead;

    return newHead;
}





int findMax(doubleList* head,doubleList* head2) {

    doubleList* tempPtr = head;
    doubleList* pointer = head2;
    int max = tempPtr->data;
    while (tempPtr) {

        if (tempPtr->data > max) { max = tempPtr->data; }
        tempPtr = tempPtr->ptrNext;
    }
    cout << "Максимум: " << max << endl << endl << endl;
    return max;
    }
void task(doubleList* head, doubleList* head2,int max) {

    doubleList* ptr = head;

    while (ptr->data!=max) {

        ptr=ptr->ptrNext;

    }

    cout << "Дошли до максимума" << endl;
    if (!ptr->ptrNext){
        cout << "Нечего добавить во второй дек, т.к. элемент крайний!"; return; 
    }
     while (ptr) { 
         head2 = push(ptr, ptr->data); 
         cout << "Добавили во второй дек: " << ptr->data << endl;
         ptr=ptr->ptrNext;
     }


}

void printDoubleList(doubleList* head) {

    doubleList* ptr = head;
    for (int i = 1; ptr != NULL; i++) {

        cout << i << " элемент дека: "<<ptr->data<<endl;

        ptr = ptr->ptrNext;
    }

}


void deleteDoubleList(doubleList* head) {

    doubleList* tempPtr;
    while (head) {

        tempPtr = head;
        head = head->ptrNext;
        delete tempPtr;


    }


}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0 ,"");
    doubleList* head = NULL;
    doubleList* head2 = NULL;
    int size;
    cout << "Введите размер дека: "; cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        int c = rand() % 100 - 50;
        cout << "Положили в дек: " << c << endl;
        head = push(head, c);

    }
    int max=findMax(head, head2);

    cout << "Первый дек: " << endl;
    printDoubleList(head);
    task(head,head2,max);
    cout << "Второй дек: " << endl;
    printDoubleList(head2);
    cout << "Деки удалены!";
    deleteDoubleList(head);
    deleteDoubleList(head2);
}
```

Comment: а вы возьмите да и нарисуйте на бумаге стрелочками, что сделает push, когда добавите  после первого элемента, У вас head  общий для всех списков(тут долго объяснять).

Comment: @ARHovsepyan к сожалению, не получается составить схему. И да, объясните, пожалуйста, насчёт общего head.